# IDE for developing in ActionScript (Flash) on Mac osx

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have problem with the autocomplete in ActionScript (Flash CS6), so I tried to change the IDE.Unfortunately I find `Flashdevelop` but it's a windows version. 
Is there IDE for developping in ActionScript (Flash) on Mac osx.

Comment: There few options you can find on the web, FDT is a plugin for Eclipse, which you can install on Mac. You may look at Adobe Flash Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Intellij IDEA (is not free like FlashDevelop), I use it and it is better then Flash Builder(I used both) it is missing a UI designer(I think there is a plugin, the developers I know hand code the UI in mxml(drag dropping is for beginners) but a UI designer is useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spend money, checkout FDT, IntelliJ IDEA and Flash Builder. If you look for something free, there's a free very limited FDT version.

Other then that there also were some standard text editor which people enhanced with some basic dev functionality, for example:

- http://www.sephiroth.it/python/sepy.php tried this some years ago and it was unstable on macs. might have improved since then.
- Textmate
- jEdit
- VI http://vrichard86.wordpress.com/2012/12/02/how-to-write-your-own-as3-project-using-vi-and-how-to-compile-it-under-ubuntu-linux-actionscript-3-0/

If you really want to develop bigger projects on a mac I would suggest using one of the paid projects, since productivty with the free products usually is noticable lower.

Answer (score 0):

I found `Sublime Text 2` (mac osx) is very simple and useful in AS3  in addition to that the autocomplete is very fast.